# why to use non-pointer for c++ fields?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

In these days I'm starting to get my feet wet with c++ and, due to my Java-ish background, I obviously have some problems in understanding some c++ features.

Since java offers only references and primitives one of the most mysterious c++ feature for me is non-pointer (and non-primitive) fields.

Here is an example of what I mean.

If I should write a c++ implementation in c++ of a list of objects of type X I would write something like:

```
class XList{
    private:

        struct node {
            X* data;
            node* next;
        };

        node* first;

    public:
        */
        a lot of methods
        */
```

}

This code is probably awful, I know about templates, STL and whatnot but the problem for me here is just the field "data". If a declare "data" as a X pointer I presume that I can use it in a way very similar to Java references.

What could be instead the reason to declare data as a X (X data;). What is the difference? I know the difference between allocating on the stack and on the heap but is there any connection here?

Please help me get a bit more of a grip on this topic.

Thank you.

--- UPDATE: ----

Most of the answers seem to focus on the difference between using the plain type on a pointer *in general*.
Probably I wrote the question in the wrong way, but I already know the difference between allocating on the stack or on the heap (the basics at least). 
What I can't understand is that in my (probably wrong) opinion the usage of a plain type in a member variables (not field, thank you for your correction) should be just some kind of corner case. Especially when templates are involved a copy of the data makes no sense to me.

Instead every time I see an implementation of some data structure the plain type is used.

E.g.: If you search "bst c++ template" on google you will find a lot of implementation like this one:

```
template<class T> 
class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
    struct tree_node
    {
        tree_node* left;
        tree_node* right;
        T data;
    };
    tree_node* root;
public:
    /*
    methods, methods and methods
    */
```

};

Do you really want to make a copy of every data of type T inserted on this tree without knowing its size? Since I'm new to the language I suppose that I misunderstood something.

Comment: "on this topic" - on pointers in general? or something else?

Comment: Others might want to clarify/correct me, but "field" really isn't C++ terminology.  You have "member variables" instead.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using an `X` instead of an `X *` is that with the pointer, you have to allocate the space for the `X` as well, which uses more space (4 bytes or 8 bytes for the pointer, plus the overhead of the allocation for the `X` via `new`), whereas with the plain type, you avoid that overhead.  So, it is simpler just to use the plain `X`.

You'd use the pointer when you definitively do not want to make a copy of the `X` value, but you could end up with dangling pointers if you are not careful.  You'd also use the pointer if there are circumstances where you might not have an object to point to.

#### Summary

1. Use the direct object to simplify memory management.
2. Use the pointer when you cannot afford copying or need to represent the absence of a value.

Comment: with the plain type, even if new is not called the constructor of the X object is still called. So I am wondering what this overhead is ? The time to allocate the memory where the object will leave ?

Comment: The overhead is the heap management, the time taken to allocate the memory where the object will live.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that a pointer points to an as yet allocated or determined hunk of memory.  But when you leave off the *, you're saying "allocated space for this entire class (not just a pointer to a class) along with this class."

The former, using a pointer, puts all the memory allocation and maintenance in your hands.  The latter just gives you the object as a member of your class.

The former doesn't use much space (what, four to eight bytes, depending on architecture?)  The latter can use a little up to a LOT depending on what the class X has as its member.

Answer (score 0):

I use non-pointer data members when: 1) I'm sure this data shouldn't and won't be shared among objects 2) I can rely on automatic deallocation when the oject is finally destroyed. A good example is a wrapper (of something to be wrapped):

```
class Wrapper
{
private:
    Wrapped _wrapped;
public:
    Wrapper(args) : _wrapped(args) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference is that if you declare an `X*` you're responsible for memory management (`new` and `delete`) on the heap, while with an `X` the memory is handled on the stack, so it's allocated/freed with the scope.

There are other subtle things as well, like worrying about assignment to self, etc.